# Why does GetAssemblyName mscorlib throw an exception?

Tags: .net, .net-assembly, mscorlib

Have a .NET 4 WinForms App. When I try to do the following:
   GetAssemblyName(@"C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\mscorlib\e0e5fbe72e8813a135fc878ff32b4bee\mscorlib.ni.dll");

I get the famous "incorrect format" exception. What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the folder name says, the mscorlib.ni.dll is a native image. It's .NET Code compiled into native machine code, so it's not a .NET Assembly anymore, and thus you cannot use reflection on it. Why are you trying to do this? The path is used internally by the .NET Runtime.

EDIT: If you encounter such a module, you will have to handle the exception and retreive information about the module differently. Either you stick with just the file name, or you use other APIs, like [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo.getversioninfo.aspx) to retreive information.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Of course I'm not explicitly calling with this filename. I have C++ Dll with .NET 4. In this dll, I explore a winform (C#, also .NET 4) process, where I look into its modules - one of them happens to be mscorlib.ni.dll. Then I reflect with the filename of this module! Is it clear? Thanks for further inputs.

Comment: I see. I updated my answer. Reflection will not work on these files.